# Displaying an image using only javascript

Tags: javascript, image

I am trying to display an image using purely javascript. I have found various examples that work using html and javascript, but no pure javascript solution. Here is the non working code I have right now,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(document.images)
        (new Image()).src="http://www.example.com/image.png";
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "http://www.example.com/image.png";
document.body.appendChild(img); //Make sure you put the element in the DOM, otherwise it won't be visible.
```